# Arduino Mega, Ubuntu, Time.h: No such file or directory

Tags: time, ubuntu

I'm using an Arduino Mega with Ubuntu 15.10.

Sadly I've got an error during compilation, that the Time.h library cannot be found. The verbose compile output shows:

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall
-fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega2560 
-DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 
-D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ 
-I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino 
-I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/mega 
-I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal 
-I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SPI 
/tmp/build6998056390288565759.tmp/Home_Guard.cpp -o /tmp/build6998056390288565759.tmp/Home_Guard.cpp.o 
**Home_Guard.ino:2:20: fatal error: Time.h: No such file or directory**
compilation terminated.
```

I've already tried to use "time.h" instead of "Time.h" but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

ok. It seems that the Ubuntu arduino package does not contain this library. The file Time.zip has to be downloaded from the authors website: http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Time.html and added in the Arduino GUI menue bar: Sketch -> Import Library -> Add Library

Comment: Since Time.h is a third party library that is not surprising.  NO Arduino package on ANY operating system contains Time.h since Time.h isn't written by Arduino.